# Django-mailer - autosend not working locally (maybe: bad localhost crontab path?)

Tags: python, django, cron, django-mailer

I'm new to django and I've installed [django-mailer 2.0](https://pypi.org/project/django-mailer/). It's working when I manually send the queued mails: `(venv)$ python manage.py send_mail`, but when I set up the crontab (which is the first time I use a cron job), it's not working. I guess there might be some mistakes in the paths.

Official documentation of django-mailer suggests:
`* * * * * (/path/to/your/python /path/to/your/manage.py send_mail >> ~/cron_mail.log 2>&1)`

Mine:

```sh
# first I tried:
* * * * * (/usr/bin/python3 /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname/manage.py send_mail >> ~/cron_mail.log 2>&1)

# then I tried:
* * * * * (/Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname/venv/bin/python /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname/manage.py send_mail >> ~/cron_mail.log 2>&1)

# also this:
* * * * * cd /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname; venv/bin/python manage.py send_mail

# I've tried Romeo's solution as well
```

None is working.. Help please!

However, when I use exactly the same command in bash, it works:

```sh
$ cd /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname
$ venv/bin/python manage.py send_mail
```

this works indeed! I'm utterly confused...

PS. about `django-mailer`: I manually sent 4 queued emails each to 2 email addresses, however, 2 got missing never delivered (not lost in junk mails either). Is this normal?

Comment: Did you get any errors or output from your cron job?

Comment: no error whatsoever... at least to my knowledge, haven't seen any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to change to the directory where the code is located and then run it:

```
* * * * * cd /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname; /usr/bin/python3 manage.py send_mail >>  /Users/username/cron_mail.log 2>&1
```

Also is better to use absolute paths in cron. And add this in script plus import your environment variables.:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /Users/username/.bash_profile #or .bashrc
cd /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname
venv/bin/python manage.py send_mail >>  /Users/username/cron_mail.log 2>&1
```

and then make the script executable:

```
chmod +rx script.sh
```

and add it in cron:

```
* * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried both, they haven't worked yet. In your first solution, after changed to the directory, should I use the python in the virtual env? or global python? Because I tried in bash that `venv/bin/python manage.py send_mail` is working, however, I repeat exactly the same code in crontab, it isn't. This is what I tried in bash: `* * * * * cd /Users/username/Documents/GitHub/projectname; venv/bin/python manage.py send_mail`

Comment: @DL8 use script and source your .bash_profile (or .bashrc). Will edit my answer with your command

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, it's still not working... I've tried everything. Don't know where could go wrong

Comment: @DL8, i forgot one `/` when source the profile. Can you try again please

Comment: Erm... still not working. When you say `chmod +rw script.sh` this command makes `script.sh` executable, does it mean after running this command, the `script.sh` file will be able to run as a command in bash? I hope not, because when I run this file directly, it says command not found

Comment: @DL8, yes, it become command, you can run it. But if you are in current directory (where the script is located) you should run it as `./script.sh`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208701/discussion-between-dl8-and-romeo-ninov).